# Iterate through firebase database using Kotlin

Tags: loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have created an array (I think):

```
var recipeArray: List<RecipeTemplate> = mutableListOf() //RecpeTemplate is a class
```

I have written out the basic `Firebase` code and verified that it works using `console.log` to print out data from the database.

In `onChildAdded()` I now want to loop the database and add the data to the array. This is what I've got:

```
override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {

            val children = snapshot!!.children 

            /*children.mapNotNullTo(recipeArray) {
                it.getValue(RecipeTemplate)<RecipeTemplate::class>
            } NOT SURE ABOUT THIS ONE*/


            children.forEach{
                var tempRecipe: RecipeTemplate? = null

                tempRecipe!!.recipeHeader = it.object["recipeHeaderFirebase"]
                tempRecipe!!.recipeText = it.object["recipeIngredientsTextFirebase"]
                tempRecipe!!.recipeImage = it.object["recipeImageFirebase"]

            }
        }
```

[image: Here] is a sample of fb data.

Not sure about the last part: `it.object`. I figure it should be something else...

Answer (score 1):

To iterate try the following:

```
override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {

        val children = snapshot!!.children
        children.forEach {
        println(it.toString())
    }
}
```

This will iterate inside the direct children of your reference and retrieve the data.